# How can I remove listener upon completion of task in closure?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a function in my program which attaches a listener to Firestore. I want to remove this listener after handling the results inside the closure.

This is what I've tried -

```
func uniqueUserName(userName : String) {


            let listener = Firestore.firestore().collection("users").whereField("userName", isEqualTo: self.userNameTextField.text!).addSnapshotListener { (snapshot, error) in

                guard let snapshot = snapshot?.documents else {fatalError()}


                if snapshot.isEmpty {
                    print("True")
                } else {
                    print("False")
                }
             }
listener.remove()
}
```

When I do this, the actions inside the closure are not being executed. I am assuming this is because the function returns before the closure is complete.

What is the correct way to remove this listener, only after the closure is completed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your listener just unregisters itself immediately in the callback, you probably don't want a listener at all.  Instead, use [getDocuments()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasefirestore/api/reference/Classes/Query#getdocumentscompletion:) to fetch the results of the query a single time, and you won't have to worry about unregistering any listeners.

Comment: with getDocuments(), I am getting the results at a specific time point. 

I planned to use addSnapshotListener so I can listen for changes in real time, in case the username becomes unavailable.

Would you still suggest I go with getDocuments instead?

Comment: What is the condition where you actually remove the listener?  If if you remove it immediately after the callback runs, it will no longer receive changes.  This listener must remain added in order to keep receiving updates.

Comment: Fair enough.

So if let's say I want to remove it once the user clicks on 'Continue' to navigate to the next screen, would I have to include the code for the segue somehow into this function?

Essentially, I want to add the listener when the text field begins editing, and remove it when the user clicks on continue. How can that be done?

Comment: You'll have to store the registration object (what you call `listener`) somewhere where it can be removed at the time you want.  I can't really tell you the right place for that, but it has to exist.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how to do that. I tried creating it in the global scope but of course that didn't work.

Can I use some kind of asynchronous dispatch method to add the code for removing the listener in queue after the closure?

Sorry if my question doesn't make perfect sense, I'm only trying to figure it out. I'll be grateful for any clues at all.

Comment: Your question is more about swift than Firestore, and it's kind of a new question altogether.  It might be worth a new question to explain more specifically what you're struggling with, from the perspective of your app's navigation.  From Firebase's perspective, you just call that unsubscribe function when you want to  stop listening.  Your new problem is how to determine when exactly that time is.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using a `getDocuments()` call as [Doug's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58433174/209103) explains, but I also want to show you why your current code doesn't work.

Right now you remove the listener right after you attach it. Since it takes some time to get your data from the servers (or the local cache), you're removing the listener before that data is even available, hence your listener never getting called.

To remove the listener after processing the data, you should remove it **inside** the callback:

func uniqueUserName(userName : String) {

```
let listener = Firestore.firestore().collection("users").whereField("userName", isEqualTo: self.userNameTextField.text!).addSnapshotListener(handleSnapshot)

func handleSnapshot (snapshot, error) {

    guard let snapshot = snapshot?.documents else {fatalError()}

    if snapshot.isEmpty {
        print("True")
    } else {
        print("False")
    }
    listener.remove()
}
```

Comment: Thanks for suggesting. I tried this and ran into the following error -

Variable used within its own initial value.

As I wrote in response to Doug, with getDocuments(), I am getting the results at a specific time point. I planned to use addSnapshotListener so I can listen for changes in real time, in case the username becomes unavailable. 
Would you still suggest I go with getDocuments instead?

Comment: 1) I changed the way the closure is declared, which should (might?) fix that problem.  2) When you attach a listener, Firestore resolves with the current data (or lack thereof) as quickly as possible. If you then remove it straight when you get that first callback, it's not a realtime listener. If you want to wait for a value, you'll need a condition around the `listener.remove()`.

Comment: That didn't work. Seems to be an issue with the way closure is declared.

Ideally I would've liked to add the listener in viewDidLoad (which can be done) and remove it in viewDidDisapper (which I can't figure out since listener is not available in that scope).

For now I have decided to use getDocuments() instead of the listener as I couldn't get a nice solution. If you can help me out, I will be grateful. Thanks